DATEDIF() Not working on the second row of TEXTSPLIT dates
I have a series of different date ranges separated by underscore. These dates are textwrapped inside a single excel cell so they appear on different lines. Please see sample details below:
CELL B2
----------------------------
| 06/13/2019 - 09/01/2019_ |
| 06/21/2021 - 08/29/2021_ |
| 08/22/2022 - 11/30/2022_ |
| 06/30/2023 - 07/28/2023_ |
| 10/03/2023 - 11/30/2023  |
----------------------------

This is the excel TEXTSPLIT I am using =IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(C2,,"_"),"") and the result is this:
CELL C
 ----------------------------
2| 06/13/2019 - 09/01/2019_ |
 ----------------------------
3| 06/21/2021 - 08/29/2021_ |
 ----------------------------
4| 08/22/2022 - 11/30/2022_ |
 ----------------------------
5| 06/30/2023 - 07/28/2023_ |
 ----------------------------
6| 10/03/2023 - 11/30/2023  |
 ----------------------------

I need to compute each DATEDIF but only the CELL C2 appeared to have a result. Let's say 2 Months. Here is the formula I am using:
CELL D2

=IFERROR(DATEDIF(IFERROR(LEFT(C2,SEARCH(" - ",C2)-1),""),IFERROR(RIGHT(C2,SEARCH(" - ",C2)-1),""),"YM"),"")&" Months"

The rest return nothing since the value is error.
I have tried to search online but no solutions were found.
Thank you for the help.

You need to get rid of the carriage return that is after the _   That is causing the issue. =SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(C2,,"_"),""),CHAR(10),"")

You could have used this formula: =BYROW(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" - "&TEXTSPLIT(C2,"_",CHAR(10),1)," - ",{1,2})," - "),LAMBDA(x, DATEDIF(TAKE(x,,1),TAKE(x,,-1),"YM"))) but I dont understand your expected output why you are using DATEDIF() function, as per MSFT this function shouldn;t be used

Alternative method: =MAP(TEXTSPLIT(C2,"_",CHAR(10),1),LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, --TEXTSPLIT(α," - "), INT((YEARFRAC(TAKE(δ,,1),TAKE(δ,,-1),1)*12))))) this 120 bytes while the last one was 132

No need for map when using YEARFRAC: =LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(C2," - ",CHAR({95;10}),1),YEARFRAC(TAKE(t,,1),DROP(t,,1),1)*12)

You could wrap the underscore and CHAR(10) in an array without using CHAR, but not using the mobile version of Excel. {"_","&"} where you should replace the ampersand with Ctrl+enter. You could update that in the answer.

You could try one of the following, the issue which you are facing is because of the carriage return as already stated by Scott Craner Sir, thus you need to remove that part as well, that said try the one of the followings:


• Formula used in cell B2
=BYROW(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(" - "&TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_",CHAR(10),1)," - ",{1,2})," - "),LAMBDA(x, 
   TEXT(DATEDIF(TAKE(x,,1),TAKE(x,,-1),"YM"),"0 \M\o\n\t\h\s;;")))


Or Using MAP() with YEARFRAC() function
=MAP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"_",CHAR(10),1),LAMBDA(α,
  LET(δ,--TEXTSPLIT(α," - "),TEXT(INT((YEARFRAC(TAKE(δ,,1),
 TAKE(δ,,-1),1)*12)),"0 \M\o\n\t\h\s;;"))))


NOTE: The use of TEXT() function which takes care of the singular and plural for those where it returns 0.

Forget about what I have posted above just use the following as commented and asked by P.b Sir to post :


=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(A1," - ",{"_";"
"},1),TEXT(INT(YEARFRAC(TAKE(t,,1),DROP(t,,1),1)*12),"0 \M\o\n\t\h\s;;"))


NOTE: That CHAR({95;10}) refers to this {"_";" "} (other than the underscore may reflect as space, but one can see by clicking on edit of my answer as well), how arrived it by selecting the CHAR() and hit F9 (Function Key) press ok. For more information please refer the commented above by @P.b Sir .


Just for fun (using YEARFRAC formatted for y/m/d)
Define dif_from_dates_string for use in multiple places, or use the function directly;
=LAMBDA(dates_from_string,
  BYROW(TEXTSPLIT(dates_from_string," - ","_" & CHAR(10)),
    LAMBDA(dates,
      LET(
        fr,YEARFRAC(INDEX(dates,,1),INDEX(dates,,2)),
        y,TRUNC(fr),m,TRUNC((fr-y)*12),d,TRUNC((fr-y-IF(m,m/12))*360),
        TEXTJOIN(" ",,IF(y,y&"y",""),IF(m,m&"m",""),IF(d,d&"d",""))
      )
)))

Then, enter f.ex. in cell C2  (needs to have at least the number of rows in the range) =dif_from_dates_string(B2)
result
2m 18d
2m 8d
3m 7d
28d
1m 27d

